# Objective-C and ARC: Why value stored to during its initialization is never read and Incompatible pointer

Tags: objective-c

when I run the analyzer tool I'm getting value stored to (jsonArr and myrrh) during its initialization is never read on lines and Incompatible pointer types assigning to 'NSMutableArray * from 'NsDictionarty *'

[image]

Comment: Please update your question with the actual code. It makes the code easier to read and reference.

Comment: Why name `jsonArr` a variable that is a **dictionary**??

Answer (score 5):

Look at the 1st two lines:

```
NSDictionary *jsonArr = [[NSDictionary alloc] init];
jsonArr = [json objectForKey:@"categories"];
```

The first line creates and assigns a new dictionary.

The second line then reassigns a new value to the same variable. This throws away the original value. Hence the warning that the value is never used.

Those two lines should simply be:

```
NSDictionary *jsonArr = [json objectForKey:@"categories"];
```

Actually, even better would be:

```
NSDictionary *jsonDict = json[@"categories"];
```

Don't name a dictionary variable with `Arr`. It's confusing. And use modern syntax.

The issues with `myArr` are the same. Though you have the additional problem of trying to assign an `NSDictionary` to an `NSMutableArray`. Those two are in no way compatible.

Perhaps `jsonArr` is properly named and its type should be `NSArray` instead of `NSDictionary`. Even then, you can't assign an `NSArray` to an `NSMutableArray`. You need to make a mutable copy:

```
NSArray *jsonArr = json[@"categories"];
NSMutableArray *myArr = [jsonArr mutableCopy];
```

Comment: Glad I could help. Please don't forget to accept the best answer to indicate that your question has been solved.

Answer (score 1):

In Obj-C variables are typed, meaning only values conforming to that variable's type may be assigned.

In your code (which is so hard to read) `myArr` is of type `NSMutableArray *` (a reference to an `NSMutableArray`) while `jsonArr` is of type `NSDictionary*` (a reference to an `NSDictionary`)

You cannot assign the value in jsonArr to myArr without a type conversion operation (cast).